# $Ax = b$ has infinite number of solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the linear system $Ax = b$ when $A$ is square ($n\times n$) and non-invertible. I saw in a paper that the system $Ax = b$:

- Has no solution if $b \notin col(A)$.
- Has infinite number of solutions if and only if $b \in col(A)$ and $dim(col(A)) < n$.

I don't understand why the second point is true (especially the condition $b \in col(A)$), can you explain me?

Comment: $b$ is a linear combinations of the $A$ columns

Comment: Astonishing what a rush people can be in to write "let me demonstrate that I once read a linear algebra textbook" in response to a question of the form "please do my linear algebra homework for me"

Comment: @nicomezi I enjoy explaining basic mathematics to people, too (it is a significant part of my job, and among the parts I prefer) but I have standards like "I will only explain things to you if there is some evidence that you are trying to understand things, rather than to copy down what I write and submit it as your own work".

Comment: @nicomezi The question is suspicious at best - it is about a standard, low-level linear algebra fact. I would expect anyone reading a (presumably research) paper to know enough linear algebra to at least recognise this fact and dredge it up. Therefore, I do not think "I saw in a paper" is sufficient context here.

Comment: @nicomezi I agree that this could be the situation here, but that is the point of requesting more context. Here, they could just cite the paper.

Comment: Ok! my mistake, I write a paper but in reality, it's more of a lecturer's notes... Here is the link to this "paper" for whom want proof that is not homework:https://utminers.utep.edu/xzeng/2017spring_math5330/MATH_5330_Computational_Methods_of_Linear_Algebra_files/ln08.pdf

Comment: @nicomezi Sorry, I missread "should" as "could". But then the underlying issue is that if the question "should" have had this, then it shouldn't have been answered in its current form. Your point that JBL should address the asker is fair enough, but it implicitly absolves you/answerers of responsibility, which I disagree with.

Comment: The reason I answered is because I felt like it was enough on the first read. My comments here were mainly motivated by the aggressivity of the first JBL's comment ("let me demonstrate that I once read a linear algebra textbook") instead of using the available tools to make constructive criticism and giving the OP directions to improve the question. @user1729

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $col(A)$ denotes the vector subspace generated by the columns of $A$. If $b \in col(A)$, it basically means that $b$ can be described by a linear combination of the columns of $A$. Furthermore a solution to $Ax=b$ is basically a vector $x$ made of the coefficients describing one such linear combination.

If $A$ is non-invertible, it means that $\exists v \ne 0$ such that $Av=0$. Thus, if $Ax_o=b$, $x_o +\mu v$ is also solution for any scalar $\mu$ since $A(x_o+\mu v)=Ax_o+\mu Av= Ax_o=b$.

Comment: Thank you! I better understand now.

Comment: You are welcome and I hope it was not homework ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the second case columns of $A$ are linearly dependent therefore exists $x_0$ such that

$$Ax_0 =0$$

then consider a solution $x_b$

$$Ax_b =b$$

therefore $\forall c\in \mathbb R$

$$A(x_b+cx_0)=Ax_b+cAx_0=b+0=b$$

which means that any $x_b+cx_0$ is also a solution.